# Empty error on starting almost-default PostgreSQL

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

When trying to start PostgreSQL, I get this 'empty' error message:

```
root@mountain-lion:/home/ubuntu# service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server
 * Error: could not exec /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/pg_ctl start -D /vol/postgres -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf" :
```

This is a freshly installed Ubuntu 11.10 server (on EC2 / Scalarium), with `postgresql-9.1` just installed via `apt-get`.

There's one change configuration value in postgresql.conf:

```
data_directory = '/vol/postgres'
```

`/vol/postgres` looks like this

```
drwx------ 5 postgres postgres   38 2012-05-18 15:13 base
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres 4096 2012-05-18 15:13 global
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   17 2012-05-18 15:12 pg_clog
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres   34 2012-05-18 15:12 pg_multixact
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   17 2012-05-18 15:13 pg_notify
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres    6 2012-05-18 15:12 pg_serial
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   24 2012-05-18 15:13 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres   17 2012-05-18 15:12 pg_subtrans
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres    6 2012-05-18 15:12 pg_tblspc
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres    6 2012-05-18 15:12 pg_twophase
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres    4 2012-05-18 15:12 PG_VERSION
drwx------ 3 postgres postgres   58 2012-05-18 15:12 pg_xlog
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  133 2012-05-18 15:13 postmaster.opts
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       36 2012-05-18 15:13 server.crt -> /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       38 2012-05-18 15:13 server.key -> /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Any idea?

**Update**: When I set `data_directory` to the default (`/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main`) it works fine, so there must be something wrong in that specific change.

Comment: Could you verify the permissions of /vol/postgres itself? ls -lha /vol/postgres

Comment: @AntonisChristofides `drwxr-xr-x 14 root root`, also it's a mount point.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides You pointed me in the right direction (see my answer). If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: That's OK, thanks, accept your own answer. Just flatter my comment above instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. First I changed the owner of `/vol/postgres` to `postgres` (after comments on the question). This resulted in the following understandable error:

```
 * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2012-05-25 07:50:13 GMT FATAL:  data directory "/vol/postgres" has group or world access
2012-05-25 07:50:13 GMT DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700).
```

So I did what it says and now it starts.