# Strange permission errors in new PostgreSQL installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, postgresql

A freshly installed PostgreSQL (with configuration overwritten) won't start:

```
$ sudo service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server
 * Error: could not read /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf: Permission denied
```

Looks like it should be able to read it though:

```
$ ls -l postgresql.conf 
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 19450 2012-06-14 10:07 postgresql.conf
```

But fine, I'll add `chmod +r` it to test if that works.

```
$ sudo chmod +r postgresql.conf 
$ sudo service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server
 * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
Error: Could not open log file /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.1-main.log
```

Huh?

```
$ ls -l /var/log/postgresql/
total 4
-rw-r----- 1 postgres adm 827 2012-06-14 10:07 postgresql-9.1-main.log
```

I don't get it. What can be wrong here? This used to work before.

Can I maybe monitor what process attempts to open the file?

---

It's Ubuntu 11.10 on EC2, using Chef. For completeness, here's the recipe:

```
# Install PostgreSQL
package "postgresql-9.1"

# Stop server
service "postgresql" do
    action :stop
end

# Overwrite configuration (setting data dir)
template "/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf" do
    source "postgresql-conf.erb"
    owner "postgres"
    group "postgres"
end

# Start server
service "postgresql" do
    action :start
end
```

Comment: First, please do not go randomly shotgunning permissions - that's ***NOT*** how you fix something, it's how you create an even bigger mess.  Instead, proceed logically with troubleshooting: `Postgres can not read/write log files it used to (and should) have access to.`  Why?  Possible reasons: (1) Is the server tryng to start/run as the `postgres` user? (Check the startup scripts) ; Are there multiple users named `postgres` with different UIDs? (check `/etc/passwd`) ; etc…

Comment: @voretaq7 I know, that was just a quick fix to try to get it to work. Once it works, I have time to figure out why exactly it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The custom configuration file (`postgresql.conf`) pointed to a data directory that did not exist. Of course, that's a problem (which I solved by setting up the data directory), but it has nothing to do with the error printed. [Once again, PostgreSQL errors not so helpful.](https://serverfault.com/questions/392267/empty-error-on-starting-almost-default-postgresql)

**Update:**

I got the same error when the data directory existed, [but with incorrect ownership](https://serverfault.com/questions/400168/force-id-of-user-created-by-apt).