# Force ID of user created by apt-get

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, filesystems

**Context:**

I'm automatically installing `postgresql-9.1` on an Ubuntu server with `apt-get`. This creates the required `postgres` user.

The Postgres data is on an external volume that survives reinstalls. This data is obviously owned by the `postgres` user.

The problem I'm having is that the ownership is not recorded under the name `postgres`, but under the UID that `postgres` had at creation time. When the server is reinstalled, `postgres` sometimes gets a different UID, and no longer owns the data directory, [and thus does not work](https://serverfault.com/questions/398722/strange-permission-errors-in-new-postgresql-installation).

---

**Question:**

Can I force the UID of the user `postgres` created by `apt-get` to something fixed? Or is there another way to solve my problem?

---

(As you may have deduced, this is on Amazon EC2 with the data on an EBS volume)

Comment: Why not just pre-create the account?

Comment: @Zoredache See Oliver's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Create your `postgres` user before installing PostgreSQL, using the correct UID.
2. Create your own custom postgresql-9.1 package which installs the stock postgresql-9.1 package and then does the `chown`.

Comment: If I create the user (option 1) with no parameters (just the UID), would apt-get configure things like the home directory?

Comment: No, of course you would need to create the user with the correct settings. See `/var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-common.postinst` for how the user is created (that's on Debian, but I'm pretty sure it is the same or very similar on Ubuntu).

Comment: If the user exists, the script skips the `adduser` part, but does all the rest.

Comment: The command used is `adduser --system --quiet --home /var/lib/postgresql --no-create-home --shell /bin/bash --group --gecos "PostgreSQL administrator" postgres`. I could easily do that before installation. Thanks for pointing me to the postinst script, that'll be good to know for other situations too.

Answer (score 1):

```
usermod -u {desired_UID} {username}
```

Stole this from here: [Lethe's blog](http://blog.tuxforge.com/change-uid-linux/)

But I actually think that a chown would be better than this, since it cannot fail on account of the `desired_UID` being already used or conflict laden in other ways.

Comment: Could work, though then I would also have to fix the ownership of various other files that apt-get creates.

Answer (score 0):

I could add a `chown` of the data directory to the server setup script, but I'd prefer a more elegant solution. Also because there are other services, like Tomcat, which have the same problem.